# Why is x 0 here, what's happening in the x=1 statement?

Tags: c++, object

```
class MyClass
{
public:
int x=0;
};

void doSomething(MyClass obj)
{
    obj.x=1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
MyClass obj;

doSomething(obj);
qDebug()<< "x is " << obj.x;

return a.exec();
}
```

I know  that if I was passing a pointer here, `x` would be `1`, my question is what's happening in the `obj.x=1`; statement here?

Comment: It's modifying a copied object. Essentially a no-op because that object then immediately goes out of scope.

Comment: @AndyG I wouldn't call it a temporary, it has a name.

Comment: @Angew: Edited for correctness

Comment: If you have problem figuring out what is happening just think as if  the function argument is a basic type instead a class, for example `void doSomething(int i) { i = 1; }`

Answer (score 2):

Inside `doSomething`, `obj` is a local variable that contains a copy of the object that was passed in from `main`. `obj.x = 1` is modifying a member of that local copy. When the function returns, this local variable is destroyed, so the assignment has no permanent effect. But if you had more code in the function, and it used `obj.x`, it would see the value `1`.